# Google Drive SDK API does not lists the file uploaded by Google Drive in java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am creating an application which can insert files into Google Drive and lists it. I am using Google Drive SDK v2 API. But my problem is it is not listing files which is not uploaded through my application. If I upload directly from Google drive it is not listed in my application.

Here is the method to list the file:

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = service.files().list();

        do {
          try {
            FileList files = request.execute();

            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
          }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
                 request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

        return result;
      }
```

and I am iterating files like this :

```
List<File> files = retrieveAllFiles(service);
        for(File f : files) {
            System.out.println("File Name : "+f.getOriginalFilename();
        }
```

Can anyone help me please ? Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I've same problem. Can you show me how to fix It?? I'm stucked with it for days

Comment: change oauth scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`

Comment: I'm working with java android. I don't know where to change that scope. Here is my code, can you take a look http://pastebin.com/pTFaVs4A

Comment: @Dolphin, Sorry dude I have no idea about android, but by changing the scope might solve your problem too.

Comment: thanks for help, I'll fingure out myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong oauth scope, probably `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` which restrict your app's access to file created or opened by your app, when you should use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` which gives full control to your app.

Comment: @PrabhatSubedi: Did Google change anything lately...changing the scope as suggested still only lists files created by my app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759077/drive-sdk-not-listing-all-my-files

Comment: @llamawithabowlcut Currently not working in Google Drive... Better look for documentation and version of SDK.