# get uploaded file name in google drive using java?

Tags: java

I want to get all file name from `google drive` using java. I get file which is uploaded from my java application but i want to get all file which is uploaded from other resources.

```
    Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
            String pageToken = null;
            do {
                FileList files = driveService.files().list()
                        .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)")
                        .setSpaces("drive")
                        .setPageToken(pageToken)
                        .execute();
                String drivefile = "";
                System.out.println("file ::: " + driveService.files().list().execute());
                for (File file : files.getFiles()) {
                    drivefile = file.getName() + "," + drivefile;

                }
```

Please tell me how can i get all file name..

Comment: give a try to this https://www.example-code.com/java/google_drive_list_files.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743049/7924858

Comment: Thank you.. But i also referred this link but  i face same problem..