# Google Drive API not shows all files from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am creating an application which can insert files into Google Drive and lists it. I am using Google Drive API. But my problem is that for some accounts it is not listing all files in my application. but for many account it shows all files perfectly

so i am no clear that what is the issue is it permission issue or another?

if in google drive folder i have set share setting with public then only it shows all folder

I have used below scope

I have used below scope........ var googlePlusOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = ""
            };googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.Drive);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveFile);            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts);
            googlePlusOptions.Scope.Add(DriveService.Scope.DrivePhotosReadonly);

Answer (score 0):

I searched the other SO ticket that is related to your problem, I found that the issue is in the setting of the scope. Make sure the scope that you use is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.`

You can also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) for more information about the SCOPE.

This are the related SO question.

- [Google Drive SDK API does not lists the file uploaded by Google Drive in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631020/google-drive-sdk-api-does-not-lists-the-file-uploaded-by-google-drive-in-java)
- [Access to all files on a user's Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331342/access-to-all-files-on-a-users-google-drive)

Comment: Please see scope which is already used i have listed it with my questions.