# Google drive API does not list all my files

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm using a pretty simple sample to retrieve my files on google drive.  There are 2 weird things

1. The first time when I run the sample, google says "the application would like to access your files blahblah".  Well, I confirmed. But, the second time, it says "the application would like to Have offline access"...  ah... why?
2. Probably(but I'm not sure), it's after I confirm it the 2nd time, I only get the files that I uploaded by this application

The code is

```
package com.google.api.services.samples.drive.cmdline;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A sample application that runs multiple requests against the Drive API. The requests this sample
 * makes are:
 * <ul>
 * <li>Does a resumable media upload</li>
 * <li>Updates the uploaded file by renaming it</li>
 * <li>Does a resumable media download</li>
 * <li>Does a direct media upload</li>
 * <li>Does a direct media download</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @author rmistry@google.com (Ravi Mistry)
 */
public class DriveSample {

  /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "testing";

  private static final String UPLOAD_FILE_PATH = "c:\\Users\\bnie\\workspace\\Servers\\.project";
  private static final String DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS = "c:\\temp";
  private static final java.io.File UPLOAD_FILE = new java.io.File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH);

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/drive_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

  /** Global Drive API client. */
  private static Drive drive;

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(DriveSample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=drive "
              + "into drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,
        JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(
        !UPLOAD_FILE_PATH.startsWith("Enter ") && !DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS.startsWith("Enter "),
        "Please enter the upload file path and download directory in %s", DriveSample.class);

    try {
      // httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
      builder.trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore());
      httpTransport = builder.build();
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
      // authorization
      Credential credential = authorize();
      // set up the global Drive instance
      drive = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
          .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
      FileList l = drive.files().list().setMaxResults(10).execute();
      List<File> files = l.getItems();

      if (files == null || files.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No files found.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Files:");
        for (File file : files) {
          System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getTitle(), file.getId());
        }
      }
      // run commands

      // View.header1("Starting Resumable Media Upload");
      // File uploadedFile = uploadFile(false);
      //
      // View.header1("Updating Uploaded File Name");
      // File updatedFile = updateFileWithTestSuffix(uploadedFile.getId());
      //
      // View.header1("Starting Resumable Media Download");
      // downloadFile(false, updatedFile);
      //
      // View.header1("Starting Simple Media Upload");
      // uploadedFile = uploadFile(true);
      //
      // View.header1("Starting Simple Media Download");
      // downloadFile(true, uploadedFile);
      //
      // View.header1("Success!");
      return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(1);
  }

  /** Uploads a file using either resumable or direct media upload. */
  private static File uploadFile(boolean useDirectUpload) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle(UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", UPLOAD_FILE);

    Drive.Files.Insert insert = drive.files().insert(fileMetadata, mediaContent);
    MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
    uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(useDirectUpload);
    uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());
    return insert.execute();
  }

  /** Updates the name of the uploaded file to have a "drivetest-" prefix. */
  private static File updateFileWithTestSuffix(String id) throws IOException {
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setTitle("drivetest-" + UPLOAD_FILE.getName());

    Drive.Files.Update update = drive.files().update(id, fileMetadata);
    return update.execute();
  }

  /** Downloads a file using either resumable or direct media download. */
  private static void downloadFile(boolean useDirectDownload, File uploadedFile)
      throws IOException {
    // create parent directory (if necessary)
    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File(DIR_FOR_DOWNLOADS);
    if (!parentDir.exists() && !parentDir.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Unable to create parent directory");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, uploadedFile.getTitle()));

    MediaHttpDownloader downloader =
        new MediaHttpDownloader(httpTransport, drive.getRequestFactory().getInitializer());
    downloader.setDirectDownloadEnabled(useDirectDownload);
    downloader.setProgressListener(new FileDownloadProgressListener());
    downloader.download(new GenericUrl(uploadedFile.getDownloadUrl()), out);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the scope that you used. Used the scope `DriveScopes.DRIVE` instead of `DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE`. For more information about scopes, check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing).

Also check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631020/google-drive-sdk-api-does-not-lists-the-file-uploaded-by-google-drive-in-java).

Comment: Do you also know the answer to my first question?  Why is it the "Offline access" at the 2nd time?  What does offline access really mean?

Comment: Try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online) and read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) for your question about offline access.

Comment: Thanks!  It perfectly answers my question